# How to set logos with different dimensions in header

Tags: php, html, css, image-resizing, graphical-logo

I am working on a project where system ask for companies to upload their logo, once they upload their logo that logo displays in the top left corner of header.

Now different companies have different logo sizes, some companies represent their logo in horizontal way some in vertical , square , circular etc etc.

In my website the logo space is in rectangular form, as it is showing in image below for phpMyAdmin logo, i wanted to manage the logo uploaded by companies from their account in the same way, whether their logo are in rectangular form or in square or circular.

[image]

It it can be achieved by html, css then it would be great, otherwise if i have to resize the logo image while uploading using php then how should i resize image in php.

Comment: You jsut need to fix the container of image(logo) to the particular height and width. All logos will acoomodate the parent container height-width and adjust themselves

Comment: simplest answer is to request hte company provides an image in a standardised size - put the onus on them to provide you the correct image.

Comment: @gavgrif I was also thinking about the same, but then i realized that it would be a bad impression for my website over companies.

Comment: nope - best for the company to provide hte image - it is their brand and their  reposnsibility. It should not be on you to manipulate their image - just to place it in the space requested.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resize image using php.You need to use either PHP's [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) or [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) functions to work with images.

But in this case you don't need these functions because you can accomplish this by using css.

```
<img src="path to logo" class="img-responsive">

.img-responsive {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Simply set a dimension limit for images to be uploaded in you code.. so companies will not be able to upload images with largest dimensions.So that you don't have to resize those images..

Comment: Thanks bilal, previously i did the same, but companies started complaining that we are not able to upload images just because of the validation, that's why i am worried about this issue, actually we are using 3 different resolution for companies logo in website , so we can't request company for 3 different resolutions, we will have to provide a user friendly environment to our customers.

Comment: ok then let them upload images with any dimensions ... and resize the image after uploading...